# Cartthrob Price modifier in view cart

Tags: cartthrob

I am trying to wrangle an events management system using Carthrob. The system will have to manage different events so in order to streamline the process as much as possible I have created a product channel called events with two price modifier fields called 'booking_options' and 'registration_details'.

Booking options allow the user to select the correct type of booking for the event (ie. day pass, full board etc) which they can do on the product details page.

'Registration_details' is set to request the relevant booking information for each event attendee (ie. name, email etc)

I have multiple items showing separately in the cart and want to add the registration_details price modifier to the cart but I can't seem to output the two modifiers separately so that the booking options show as a select dropdown and the registration details appear as text inputs for each item.

I have read through all the documentation but I am still stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding individual item option fields in the cart that allows the user to fill in their registration details.
I am going to use playa to allow the person setting up the event to select the registration fields they require.